# Will we get exact time a configuration change happened using AWS Config service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, amazon-cloudtrail

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-sns-notification.html) I find that we get **configurationItemCaptureTime** for every configuration change that happens.

For eg., I created a volume at 5:46, but the SNS event had configurationItemCaptureTime which is 5:53. Maybe this is because the system took note of only the [time when the change was recorded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_ConfigurationItem.html). But I would like to know, when the actual change was made, instead of when the change was recorded.

Is there a way to get the exact time the change was made ?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "capture time" and "resource change time" (capture time may be notably later) - are you looking for `NotificationCreateTime`? (note - there are a few different timestamps provided in AWS Config so it may be a different one, and from my understanding, each underlying service has its own resource properties it provides to AWS Config)

Comment: Again, that is the time when the notification was made in SNS. it is not the time when the change was actually made.

Comment: Honestly, the best way to figure this out is to take a look through a sample event to see if it includes the timestamp you expect - it might be buried in there and not documented. If it's not there, then you'll need to reach out to AWS and get them to add/fix the missing feature. Best you can do otherwise is add your own polling/lookup - when you receive an event, look at the resource itself for its last-modified-time, but that'll probably fail for multiple modifications in quick succession

Comment: I did that already.. Thats why i was able to quote that example . here is the response json . https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/fcbb01515d11044d04bde14a3d9f6e7a